# How to map the segment boundaries to the closest position in reference file in R

Tags: r, bioinformatics

How can i map the coordinate positions (start and end positions) in segment file to the nearest position in reference file.

```
seg <- Sample   Chromosome  Start        End        Num_markers LogRatio
        Nf1         1      3020000.5    195340000.5     4732    0.2981
        Nf2         2      3100000.5    181980000.5     4091    0.2986

Ref <- Name       Chromosome    Position
     1:3010000.5        1       3010000.5
     1:195330000.5      1     195330000.5
     2:3090000.5        2       3090000.5
     2:181970000.5      2     181970000.5
```

Desired out put

```
result <- Sample  Chromosome    Start     End       Num_markers LogRatio
          Nf1       1         3010000.5 195330000.5  4732        0.2981
          Nf2       2         3090000.5 181970000.5  4091        0.2986
```

Comment: Why do we have decimals on genomic positions, `.5`?

Comment: How does Position 3090000.5 from Chromosome 1 in Ref becomes a match to Position 3100000.5 in Chromosome 2?

Comment: @ zx8754 i updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`, you could perform two rolling joins while specifying `roll = "nearest"`. You would need to this twice as you need to join to different columns each time but this should be very efficient. Here's a possible implementation

```
library(data.table)
setDT(seg)
setDT(Ref)
StartInd <- Ref[seg, on = c(Chromosome = "Chromosome", Position = "Start"), which = TRUE, roll = "nearest"]
EndInd <- Ref[seg, on = c(Chromosome = "Chromosome", Position = "End"), which = TRUE, roll = "nearest"]
seg[, `:=`(Start = Ref[StartInd, Position], End =  Ref[EndInd, Position])]
print(seg, digits = 10)
#    Sample Chromosome     Start         End Num_markers LogRatio
# 1:    Nf1          1 3010000.5 195330000.5        4732   0.2981
# 2:    Nf2          2 3090000.5 181970000.5        4091   0.2986
```

Comment: im getting Error in                                                                                              [.data.table`(Ref, seg, on = c(Position = "Start"), which = TRUE,  : 
  unused argument (on = c(Position = "Start"))

Comment: You have an old version of `data.table`. Please install v 1.9.6 from CRAN

Comment: I was trying the script on a bigger data set with first few columns given in the example above.   Im getting   Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(seg, , `:=`(Start = ref[StartInd, Position], End = ref[EndInd,  :
  Supplied 10795 items to be assigned to 741 items of column 'Start' (10054 unused)
2: In `[.data.table`(seg, , `:=`(Start = ref[StartInd, Position], End = ref[EndInd,  :
  Supplied 9637 items to be assigned to 741 items of column 'End' (8896 unused)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I've tried it on different data sizes and it works fine. Maybe you are doing something incorrectly. The sizes of `StartInd` and `EndInd` should be the same as `seg` *by definition* - hence your error message doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: in my case the the mapping of the coordinates should be done only if the "Chromosome" of Ref and seg are same

Comment: So just add `Chromosome` to the join. I've updated the answer